# Retrieving a full row of google sheets data to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to build a form that can recall data based on a specific number being inputted using Google Scripts and JavaScript. When a number is inputted the JavaScript should call the Google Scripts so that it can locate the values I need based on the number. For example bellow is a google sheets. I want when the user inputs a number it searches for that value in column C and then grabs the data from that row. Ex. if the number is 14 then values: 2021-05-12, 5, 6 and 7 are returned to the JavaScript.

UPDATED:
[image]

Everything I want is working however, when I try to retrieve the date from the array in the JavaScript it does not work. The numbers are the only thing functioning. I know the date is in the array as I can see it in the logs.

JavaScript:

```
  function callDataRetriever(){
    var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(dataRetriever).retreiveData(number);
  }

  function dataRetriever(data){
    document.getElementById("location").value = data[0]; //This works
    document.getElementById("dateOpened").value = data[1]; //This does not work. Stops the function from continuing its task.        
    document.getElementById("value1").value = data[2]; //Without the date everything here down works
    document.getElementById("value2").value = data[3];
    document.getElementById("value2").value = data[4];
    document.getElementById("value4").value = data[5];
    //...
  }
```

Google Scripts (I have 28 total values) Everything here works perfectly as seen in the logs bellow.

```
function retreiveData(number){
  var url = "urlToSpreadsheet";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var data = ws.getRange(1,1, ws.getLastRow(), ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dataValues = [];
  var filterData = data.filter(
    function(r){
      if(r[2] == number){
        var i = 3;
        while(i < 29){
          dataValues.push(r[i]);  
          i++;
        }
      }
    }
  )
  return dataValues;
}
```

[image]

I am not sure if the problem lies in the way the date is formatted.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter to perform the operation you want

```
var filterData = data.filter(
  function(r){
    //Select the index init in 0 in your case is 2
    return r[0] == 'YOUR_SEARCH_VALUE'
  }
)    
// Use your filter data
ui.alert(filterData[0]) //data[row][column]
```

Comment: adding here that you need to remove the `r[0]` in your result since OP only wants the values. OP can use  ```if (r[0] == number) return r.shift();``` alternatively.

Comment: Macorreag, @NaziA Thank you for your inputs they both together helped me in solving my problem. I have a new problem now where the date is not transferring over to my JavaScript function causing my function to stop. Do you have any input on this?

Comment: That's another question, try looking in the app script documentation, you need to set a Date object in Javascript and use Utilities.formatDate.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When `number` is given and run the function `retreiveData`, you want to search the value of `number` from the cells "C4:C" of "Data" sheet, and want to retrieve the values of the columns "D", "E" and "F" for the searched row.

In this case, I would like to propose to use TextFinder. When the TextFinder is used, searching value is run in the internal server side. By this, the process cost will be a bit low. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/0a6f03970b471ffa286f1dac0b79359e)

When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this case, please modify `retreiveData` at Google Apps Script side as follows.

```
function retreiveData(number){
  var url = "linkToSpreadsheet";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var data = ws.getRange("C4:C" + ws.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(number).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  if (data) {
    return data.offset(0, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0];
  }
  return Array(4).fill("No value");
}
```

And, please modify `dataRetriever` at Javascript side as follows.

```
function dataRetriever(data){
  console.log(data) // Here, you can check the value from `retreiveData` at the console.
  data.forEach((v, i) => {
    document.getElementById(`value${i + 1}`).value = v;
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- In this case, when the search value of `number` is not found, `No value` is put to the input tags of `value1` to `value4`. When you want to modify this, please modify `return Array(4).fill("No value");` for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Process Costs for Searching Values in Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/0a6f03970b471ffa286f1dac0b79359e)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

```js
var data = [
    [1,  55, 5545,   54,   51],
    [2,  45,  541,  848, 1215],
    [3, 323, 3232,  215, 3051],
    [4,  13, 5151, 1513, 2315]
]

number = 3;


// via object where the 'numbers' are keys

var data_obj = Object.fromEntries(data.map(d => [d[0], d.slice(1,)]));
console.log(data_obj[number]); // [ 323, 3232, 215, 3051 ]


// via filter (about the same as @macorreag's answer)

var res = data.filter(d => d[0] == number)[0].slice(1,);
console.log(res); // [ 323, 3232, 215, 3051 ]
```

An object makes sense in the cases when you need to extract info from the same data several times. For single requests a filter looks better, I think.

And if the numbers always start from 1 and go sequentially 2, 3, 4, 5, ... etc, the simpliest solution is an array and its indexes:

```js
var data = [
    [1,  55, 5545,   54,   51],
    [2,  45,  541,  848, 1215],
    [3, 323, 3232,  215, 3051],
    [4,  13, 5151, 1513, 2315]
]

var number = 3;

var data_array = data.map(d => d.slice(1,));
console.log(data_array[number-1]); // [ 323, 3232, 215, 3051 ]
```

In this case you don't even need the first column 'numbers' at all. You can just extract the next four columns and get the rows by indexes (-1): number 1 is  `data[0]`, number 2 is `data[1]` etc.